# How to send a message to WIN10 action center?

Tags: winforms, windows-10

In order to make a quickstar/launcher,I want to make a resident message always show in action center,that would be unable to clear this message like android moblie top notification untill close my app.

and once click this message,my function launched,and message will still show in the action center.
[image]

I would be like to use WinForm to accomplish it,it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Only balloon notifications (Toasts) end up in action center. If user doesn't respond to a notification or click "close" it ends up in action center. When user clicks on it, it is marked as "read" and goes away. I don't think it is possible to create a non-dismissable message in action center. However you can create your own custom form outside action center like in corner of desktop